# MacPorts manual port location

Tags: python, macports

I am installing one library for python from MacPorts. But macports version of the library is older than actual development svn version. Is it possible to specify a custom location for a port installation in MacPorts so I could install latest library from the developer's site?

Comment: Be more specific. Is it an older version of Python or the library in question? Do you want to run the older and newer libraries in parallel? If so, why?

Comment: I edited the question to be more specific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Have](http://guide.macports.org/chunked/development.local-repositories.html) a look here, you have to install a local portfile repositories.

Comment: It would be good if you submit a patch to MacPorts with your update, so everyone can get the new version. Please refer to http://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want the latest version, couldn't you just not install the old version?

If you are planning to build and deploy the svn version yourself and want to test it while not removing the old version, you might find virtualenv useful. It allows you to deploy a parallel Python environment with its own independent set of libraries.

I'm still not clear on your requirements, so I hope the above helps somehow.