# Install PRAW with MacPorts Python

Tags: python, macports, reddit

#### Question

How can I install [PRAW](https://github.com/praw-dev/praw/wiki) with a MacPorts version of python?

It seems like there is no port for it.

#### What I tried

The closest thing I've found to this question is: [MacPorts manual port location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566357/macports-manual-port-location), so I mucked around with trying to make my own port for it, but I really don't know what I'm doing.

I know that I could install it with `pip` for a non-MacPorts version of Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is no need for a platform-specific version of PRAW. Using `pip` or `easy_install` is the recommended way to get the most up-to-date python packages as [PyPI](http://pypi.python.org/pypi), the Python Package Index, is to python packages what MacPorts, (or Brew, Fink, etc), is to OSX-specific packages.

As the PRAW package maintainer, I would prefer that you do not create platform-specific packages, simply because they are unnecessary and more importantly because they become out-of-date very quickly.

If you are worried about cluttering the namespace of your system's python, then I suggest you use [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv), or the built-in virtual environment features if you are using python 3.3.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that I'm an idiot who didn't understand that macports could install its own version of `pip` as well. Here's how I finally got PRAW working:

```
sudo port install py27-pip
sudo pip-2.7 install praw
```

I really need to get this virtualenv thing figured out...